# swagger wrong api for different servlets

Tags: java, swagger-core

I have several endpoints. For example

```
@ApplicationPath("/endpoint_1")
public class Endpoint1 extends ResourceConfig {


 public Endpoint1(){
    register(SomeObject1.class);
    ...
    }

}

@Path("/path1")
public class SomeObject1 {
}


@ApplicationPath("/endpoint_2")
public class Endpoint2 extends ResourceConfig {

public Endpoint2(){
    register(SomeObject2.class);
    ...
    }

}


@Path("/path2")
public class SomeObject2 {
}
```

And when I try to register swagger and get API for both endpoints, I get only for 1 and its swagger's endpoint

I have tried many variants but this one was last one

```
@ApplicationPath("/swagger")
public class OpenApiCOnfig extends ResourceConfig {

  public OpenApiConfig() {
    OpenApiResource r = new OpenApiResource();
    SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
                .openAPI(new OpenAPI())
                .prettyPrint(true);

    r.setOpenApiConfiguration(oasConfig);

    register(r);
  }
}
```

and I get API like

/swagger/path1; /swagger/path2;

How to get correct API like

endpoint_1/path1;  endpoint_2/path2

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve cannot be done with @ApplicationPath. Remove them and build that part of the path in the @Path annotations.

```
@Path("/endpoint_1/path1")
public class SomeObject1 {
}


@Path("/endpoint_2/path2")
public class SomeObject2 {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't do that , because it is like 2 different big endpoints for core and additional part of application. We have 2 different classes which extends ResourceConfig class

Comment: I don't understand what in having a core/additional structure prevents using concatenated '@Path over '@ApplicationPath. Is core using ApplicationPath and can't be modified?

Comment: because it seems I have to remake all pathes from our all controllers to new path?

Comment: That should have been considered when building the core application with a '@ApplicationPath. That mandates the path for the application - both core and extensions.